# Compare working copy with specific repository

Tags: svn, repository, working-copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SVN diff across 2 different repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221215/svn-diff-across-2-different-repositories)

How can I compare a working copy with a repository different than the one which the working copy is associated?

I need this comparison, because I was forced to apply some changes directly on the production server (current version connected to a tag) and I would like to check if those changes were already applied on trunk.

Comment: Is it a different repository or just a different branch/tag within the same repo?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout both and use a diff tool like `Kdiff3`

Comment: Isn't possible to compare them directly using the svn cli? (comparison between the working copy available on the production server and a specific repository identified by its url)

Comment: I am not aware of any. In SVN you can use partial checkout. So you just need to checkout that specific directory.

Comment: There are many local changes. I would have to checkout the entire project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to compare against a specific revision then you can create a patch of the working copy and a patch of the specific revision in the other repo and then do a diff to see if the patch files match or not.

Or if you have TortoiseSVN installed you can do the following:

> Difference to another branch/tag
>
> If you want to see what has changed on trunk (if you are working on a branch) or on a specific branch (if you are working on trunk), you can use the explorer context menu. Just hold down the Shift key while you right click on the file. Then select TortoiseSVN → Diff with URL. In the following dialog, specify the URL in the repository with which you want to compare your local file to.

Source: [Viewing Differences](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html)