# How to get a list of differences two two different urls using subversion

Tags: svn

Say I have url1 and url2. I want to get a list of differences between the two. Specifically:

1. If the file is present in both url1 and url2 and different I want to be able to tell it's been modified
2. If the file is present in url1 but not in url2 I want to tell it's been deleted
3. If the file is present in url2 but not in url1 I want to tell it's been added

Is this possible with subversion?

Comment: Subversion alone probably can't do it, but calling `svn status` on both copies, and comparing the output in some sophisticated script could get the job done.

Comment: Assume the two URLs are brand new, i.e. their modification history is blank.

Comment: Subversion alone probably can't do it (not its job) but some directory comparison tool probably could help. I remember Total Commander to have this asymmetrical compare feature, just like you described it.

Comment: However, see the second answer to this question. Maybe I got it wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1221215/395718